# Omnet++ , veins , the number of neighbors nodes for Car X in specific time

Tags: omnet++, veins

My question: how can I compute/find the number of neighbors nodes for Car X in specific time (targeted nodes in range of car X), from the results or by updating the code ?

In Beacon broadcasting, to compute the ratio of successfully received packet for a node X ,I think that I need to know the number of nodes(cars) that exist in the region of this car X.

Comment: How would you define "in range"?

Comment: I used a realistic model 2 Km X 2 Km , then each second one car will be added to the model ,   when I finished the run and get the results I got confused , how I compute the probability of successfully received packet for any node , and for the model completely.  please check this question have more information about the case : [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105527/omnet-veins-asking-about-the-value-of-recievedbeacon-and-sentpacket)    I think that knowing about the neighbors of nodes in **transmission range** ex: circle of 200/300m around the node can give me accurate results.